# Order weekly international events saved only with day, hour, minute?

Tags: php

I have weekly international events saved with day, hour, minute, somewhat like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event] => Pear festival
            [city] => London
            [country] => UK
            [local-day] => Saturday
            [local-time] => 09:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event] => Apple festival
            [city] => New York
            [country] => US
            [local-day] => Saturday
            [local-time] => 10:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event] => Kiwi festival
            [city] => Wellington
            [country] => NZ
            [local-day] => Saturday
            [local-time] => 11:00
        )
)
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to order these chronologically by UTC. I guess this is easy enough if I add the current local time zone to each event before the data is saved. However, countries have summer time and standard time. For example, New Zealand is currently on NZST, which is UTC+13, but after March they return to DST UTC+12.

Anyhow, as things currently stand (January 2021), these events would be ordered:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event] => Kiwi festival
            [city] => Wellington
            [country] => NZ
            [utc-day] => Friday
            [utc-time] => 22:00
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [event] => Pear festival
            [city] => London
            [country] => UK
            [utc-day] => Saturday
            [utc-time] => 09:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event] => Apple festival
            [city] => New York
            [country] => US
            [utc-day] => Saturday
            [utc-time] => 14:00
        )
)
```

But after March, the NZ time would be an hour out, and the same for the other countries when they switch to summer time.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a column in the events table which will store timestamp of your event in UTC no matter this the region event is happening in.

You can use PHP's default [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class or widely accepted libraries like [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to get the UTC timestamp from a date. You already have the countries and the time in the table. So when you save the event, generate its UTC timestamp and save. And for already existing events, you can do that in bulk once.

This way you can just order your events directly by the UTC timestamps column. This will also help you a lot in longer run if you want to get all events which will happen on a specific date and time, you can check that directly using the UTC timestamp column.

On a side note, this is also helpful in a way that you would have no date logic in your MySQL query other than the one to order results.

Comment: I agree with Mihir solution.  But you don't need Carbon.  You can use PHP's DateTime class, e.g. https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: Totally @Alan I agree, you can use PHP core functions to do this. :) Carbon just gives syntactic sugar which Kinda like..